# Fourier transformation of Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, hamiltonian

I'm currently reading QFT for the gifter amateur and I came across the Hamiltonian for a linear monatomic chain of N atoms:
$$H=\sum_j \frac{\hat{p}_j^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}K(\hat{x}_{j+1}-\hat{x}_j)^2,$$
where $R_j=ja$ is the position of each atom and $x_j$ is the displacement.  The author begins to tranform the Hamiltonian to reciprocal space by using
$$\hat{x}_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt[]N} \sum_k \hat{\tilde{x}}_ke^{ikja},$$
and
$$\hat{p}_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt[]N} \sum_k \hat{\tilde{p}}_ke^{ikja}.$$
I've never seen this Fourier transformation before, and all I can find is the Fourier transform of a *function* (defined with an integral) not an *operator*.  I'm confused, what is this transformation and where can I find more information about it?

Comment: Which edition, section and equation(s)?

Comment: First edition, page 25, section 2.4, equations 2.45 - 2.49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called **Discrete Fourier Transforms**.
We define discrete Fourier transform $g_p (p=0, 1, 2, \dots, N-1)$ of a function $f$ is

$$
g_p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f_k \, e^{2\pi ikp/N}
$$

Inverse Fourier transform is defined in similar way,

$$
f_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{p=0}^{N-1} g_p \, e^{-2\pi ijp/N}
$$

Refer Arfken, 7th Edition, 20.6, Page-1004